# The channel provided must be a voice channel. error with move_member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import time

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print ("Ready")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Move(ctx):
    #channel to move to '414543063575429131'
    #user to move '192361974053470208'
    await bot.move_member('192361974053470208', '414543063575429131')
    print("done")


bot.run("token_here")
```

This is my code but I when I try to move the user it gives me the error "The channel provided must be a voice channel."

I know the bot works because I had some simple commands earlier that would reply to messages earlier and they worked fine.

I am new to python and discord bots so I don't really know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channel argument to `move_member` must be a `Channel` object, not just the channel id.  This is noted in the [documentation for `move_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.move_member)

> You cannot pass in a [`Object`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Object) instead of a [`Channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel) object in this function.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def move(ctx):
    destination = '414543063575429131'
    user = '192361974053470208'
    await bot.move_member(ctx.message.server.get_member(user), bot.get_channel(destination)) 
    # The get_member doesn't look to be strictly necessary, but it doesn't hurt
    # and improves readability
    print("done")
```