# Play audio in vc discord using discord.py - InvalidArgument: Channel passed must be a voice channel

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I tried to play audio using discord.py, while I join in voice chat, but I face a problem:

> InvalidArgument: Channel passed must be a voice channel

How can I make it work?

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game

Client = discord.client
client = Bot('.')
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def yt(ctx):
url = ctx.message.content
url = url.strip('yt')

author = ctx.message.author
voice_channel = author.voice_channel
vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
player.start()

client.run('my Token')
```

After that I tired to play the video, after I joined the voice channel:

```
(.yt https://www.youtube.com/watc........)
```

#### Error list:

Ignoring exception in command yt

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Hema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Hema\Desktop\Music - Copy - Copy.py", line 21, in yt
vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
File "C:\Users\Hema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\discord\client.py", line 3172, in join_voice_channel
raise InvalidArgument('Channel passed must be a voice channel')
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Channel passed must be a voice channel

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Hema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
yield from command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\Hema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Hema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an 
exception: InvalidArgument: Channel passed must be a voice channel
```

Comment: In error log: "Channel passed must be a voice channel"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The channel provided must be a voice channel. error with move\_member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847080/the-channel-provided-must-be-a-voice-channel-error-with-move-member)

Comment: Are you in a voice channel on the server you send the message on when you call this command?

Comment: yehh
@PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 0):

the `voice_channel = author.voice_channel`is the error replace it with
`voice_channel = author.voice.channel` good luck :)